# Programmatically select page number

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-jtable

I have a JTable with multiple pages, and I'd like to be able to save the page the user is on in a session variable and automatically move the table to that page when they come back to it. Is there a way to change the page the JTable is on when it loads?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code it does not appear there are any public methods to alter the page number, however you can do this as a workaround:

```js
var pageNumberToChangeTo = 3;

$("#IDofMyTable").find(".jtable-goto-page select").first().val(pageNumberToChangeTo).trigger("change")
```

Comment: haha yah just how dump it is. I also looked at the code there is no GotoPage or even CurrentselectedPage or somthing like those.